# FileHelpers library ignoreFirstLine issue

Tags: c#, excel, csv, filehelpers

I have a CSV file which I am trying to import using file Helpers Library, issue is I get the spree sheet files from somewhere and save them as CSV to be able to import them but the first line has Wrap-text excel properties which make the cell into multiple line which in excel is only single row/cell but in CSV it counts as more than one, it shows like this in CSV:

"The Student id ", name, sex

instead of

The Student id , name, sex

so when I use ignore first line property of File Helpers, it assumes "The Student id ", is a line and  name, sex is another line.

any help apart from format my excel file before importing ?

Comment: Does it need to be an excel document?  I would start with .csv, or tab separated values (which excel knows what to do with)

Comment: I get the files as excel document and then save them as CSV to be able to import them, the files need to be in CSV format

Answer (score 0):

Excel is still not very good at exporting a simple CSV file.

You need to export all fields with both quotes and delimiters. Use [this great macro](https://gist.github.com/fabriceleal/7803969) instead to export the CSV correctly. See [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/397853/111397) for more information.